# PostgreSQL - Groups into columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

There is a table with prices

```
city_id product_id  price
1       1           1
1       2           2
1       3           3
2       1           4
2       2           5
2       3           6
```

Is it possible to show cities as columns?

```
procuct_id  city_1  city_2 ... city_n
1           1       4
2           2       5
3           3       6
```

Comment: [Crosstab questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+and+%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do pivot as following. here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/soptEdEcLxWLHTuHfXXjP9/2).

```
select
    product_id,
    max(case when city_id = 1 then price end) as city_1,
    max(case when city_id = 2 then price end) as city_2,
    max(case when city_id = 3 then price end) as city_3,
    .
    .
    max(case when city_id = n then price end) as city_n
from myTable
group by
    product_id
```

Output:

```
| product_id | city_1 | city_2 |       | city_n |
| ---------- | ------ | ------ |...... |------- |
| 1          | 1      | 4      |       |        |
| 2          | 2      | 5      |       |        |
| 3          | 3      | 6      |       |        |
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend conditional aggregation for this.  Postgres supports the (standard and) very handy `filter` clause:

```
select product_id,
       max(price) filter (where city_id = 1) as city_1,
       max(price) filter (where city_id = 2) as city_2,
       max(price) filter (where city_id = 3) as city_3
from myTable
group by product_id;
```

The only caveat is:  If you don't know the specific cities you want, then you need some sort of dynamic SQL.